# how do you get your computer not to run out of memory with the system syncing

Tags: bitcoin-core, memory

after choosing a wallet Bitcoin core, they have a 7 years system sync which i am a first time user.  I didn't know that and money was sent to the account.  I can't access the money.  It is not showing up.  Back to the issue besides where is my money.  My computer can't upload all the syncing because it is running out of memory.  I backed up my computer erased most of the backup and still don't have enough memory.  so someone please tell my way your app takes up and over my whole computer.  Please get this to work as i am not a tech person or anything but i am extremely disappointed with the tech side trying to help.

Answer (score 2):

You can configure Bitcoin Core to run with `--dbcache=50` which will limit the database cache size to 50MB (default is 100MB).  You can read more about it [here](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Running_Bitcoin).

Alternatively, you probably don't need to be running a full node, and should instead consider using an [SPV wallet](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Thin_Client_Security), which will consume a lot less of your system resources.

Comment: Also suggest reducing the memory pool size, signature cache size, and number of connections.

Comment: In recent versions, the default dbcache is 300.

Comment: but where do you add the --dbcache=50  i tried doing something like this before in the properties off the app and it didn't work.  I know nothing about programming and it sound foreign to me.

Comment: @fightofthedog, you put either put `--dbcache 50` when running from the command line, or you put `dbcache=50` into your bitcoin.conf config file.  You really should read https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Running_Bitcoin

Comment: I don't understand the language of it since i am not a tech person.  I just want my money and i am tired of waiting for it.  is there a customer support i can call and have it changed.  I don''t get what you are saying.  I found one i don't have to download for days and it is very simple to use besides this one.  But since i am not a computer guy looks like you guys code these things so people like me loss there money by giving up.  I will not recommend this product to anyone in my company or elsewhere.

Comment: maybe there should be a video toturial for this app. for people like me that don't understand that programming.  it's simple to you and a few others but it is not to some either.  I simply just want my money and that is it.  i don't want to do programming or anything else with this.  My computer is maxed out on memory thanks to this dumb app and still is not synced.

Comment: @fightofthedog, you have made some very inaccurate assumptions.  This is not a product forum, it's a question and answer site.  Nobody here is being paid, nor does anyone here necessarily represent any Bitcoin related product.  You found the forum, and asked a technical question.  I gave a technical answer, and provided links to resources that would help you understand it, and clarified when you asked.  An actual developer of the project added to my answer with more suggestions.  Considering that nobody here owes you anything, I think you've been treated quite well so far.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you've got money in a wallet already?

Perhaps a better option is to get a lightweight wallet client and then get the wallets managed in that.

That way you can avoid having to sync the entire blockchain on your machine.